# My Gnome shell in Ubuntu is the old-style gnome 2.0 style

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I have upgraded from Natty to Oneiric. I want to use Gnome shell 3 in Oneiric, and have installed it from the repository. When I login I see the old gnome 2.* style desktop. Is this the expected result? Shouldn't the interface be the same as gnome-shell. I am confused since different posts on the Internet are showing both interfaces.

Comment: could you tell us which graphic card you have? it might be perfectly possible that gnome falls back to the classic desktop if you do not have a 3d acceleration graphic card.

Comment: I am using a 64 bit system with NVidia GeForce GT 540 graphics card. The proprietary nvidia drivers cannot be used, because then my GUI login gets stuck. So, I am currently using nvidia-current from the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

When you were asked to login, you clicked on the button that says you can choose

- **Gnome**
- Gnome Classic
- Gnome Classic (No Effect)
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu 2D

you should chose Gnome.

what version did you chose ?

Comment: I am using Gnome to login.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome Shell requires that you have a graphics accelerator and good drivers. What you're describing is Gnome Panel 3, which is provided as a fallback for Gnome Shell when it can't be used.

Comment: I am using a 64 bit system with NVidia GeForce GT 540 graphics card. The proprietary nvidia drivers cannot be used, because then my GUI login gets stuck. So, I am currently using nvidia-current from the repositories.

Comment: Right. Then you can't use Gnome Shell, it seems.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot uses [Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29) not [GNOME Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell).
If you want to use GNOME Shell, then install the gnome-shell package, this can be done with `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`.

In the login manager (LightDM), which you see when you boot Ubuntu, you can click on the gear icon to chose which session to use when you login.

Comment: I have installed gnome shell, and use the gear icon to choose the login environments.